# 5x ≡ 3 (mod 12) how do you find the first three xs without listing them?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

5x ≡ 3 (mod 12).

The question asked me to find the smallest positive non zero integers that can be plugged in the place of x.

I only know how to find the answer by making a list.

> 5, 10, ***3***, 8, 1, 6, 11, 4, 9, 2, 7, 0, 5, 10, ***3***.

It took 12 for 3 to get back to another 3.
So the answer is 3, 15(=3+12), 27(=3+12+12).

But is there any shortcut or formula to get them more easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Euclidean algorithm to find the multiplicative inverse,

$$12=2(5)+2$$

$$5=2(2)+1$$

Hence, we have $$1=5-2(2)=5-2(12-2(5))=5(5)-2(12)$$

Hence $$1 \equiv 5(5) \pmod{12}$$

$$5^{-1} \equiv 5 \pmod{12}$$

$$5x \equiv 3 \pmod{12}$$

Multiplying by the $5^{-1}=5$ on both sides,

$$x\equiv 5(3)\equiv 15 \equiv 3 \pmod{12}$$

Comment: Thank you, but how do you find 27 then? sorry i'm dumb

Comment: The solution are of the form of $12k+3$ where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, when $k=2$, you get $27$. You are not dumb, you are just new to the topic =).

Comment: oh right XD I'm so dumb

Answer (score 1):

$5\cdot5=25\equiv1\operatorname{mod}12$, so multiplying both sides of the congruence by $5$ gives $x\equiv15\equiv3\operatorname{mod}12$.

Answer (score 0):

$5$ and $12$ are coprime, so by Bezout some linear combination is $1$.  Indeed, $5\cdot5+(-2)12=1$.  Thus, $5^{-1}\equiv5\bmod{12}$.

So solve the congruence by multiplying by $5^{-1}\equiv5$ on both sides.  Get $x\equiv3\bmod{12}$.